# Gnuplot: How to change offset of single xtics?

Tags: gnuplot, axis-labels

I have a couple of irregular xtics on the second x axis whose text labels overlap partly, and so I would like to change the offset of some of them individually. For example, I have:

```
set x2tics nomirror in rotate ("A" 218,"Z" 210,"D" 199,"SW" 176)
```

and would like to add another tic somewhere in between. The above tics have their text labels outside the box, so I wanted to put the additional one inside:

```
set x2tics nomirror in rotate offset 0,-3 add ("SI" 196)
```

However, this changes the offset of *all* tic labels in the same way. Is there a method of manipulating them individually?

I'm using Gnuplot 5.2p2.

Thomas

Comment: I'm not sure if you can specify an offset for individual tic labels, but as a workaround you can create the tic with an empty label and add the label text separately: `set label "SI" at second 196, graph 0.95 rotate`.

Comment: Yes, the solution with a label would be a workaround, but it's a rather cumbersome one, and I would prefer to avoid it if possible. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `multiplot` to superimpose a second plot with just the tic?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to move tic labels "in" and "out" individually. Actually, they are all out, but offset by a constant value and shifted individually by multiples of a newline which is defined in a data column.

**Script:**

```
### move tics individually "in" or "out"
reset session

$myTics <<EOD
A    218   2
Z    210   2
D    199   2
SW   176   2
SI   196   0
XY   230   0
ABC  160   0
EOD

set xtics nomirror
set x2range[150:250]
set x2tics out offset 0,-2.2
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y

TicOff(col1,col2) = strcol(col1).substr("\n\n\n\n",1,int(column(col2)))

plot sin(x), \
     $myTics u 2:(NaN):x2tic(TicOff(1,3)) axes x2y1
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]